# Can't get extensions or scripts to install in Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, browser

As the title says, I can't seem to get Chrome to install extensions or scripts.  I can seem to get extensions from the webstore to install, but nothing else seems to work.  It just downloads a copy of the extension or script to my default download folder.  I've tried to open the file directly in Chrome, but it just creates another copy of the file.

I've done a fresh install and tried all three channels and still came up with the same result. However, I tried a Chromium build and had no problems.  Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Comment: Is your chrome directory in the default place under your Users folder or have you junctioned it off somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, chrome is in the default directory with the other google programs.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug, promptly corrected after a few days..For more details see [chromium issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=129150).